# When I use gdbAttach to a remote process, I am prompted that the file cannot be opened

Tags: gdb

When I attach to the remote process using GDB, I am prompted that the ** file cannot be opened and the file cannot be read. In fact, I do not have the file. How can I remove or disable the prompt?